# Is cooking a raw steak in the microwave safe?

Tags: food-safety, microwave, steak

I only have a microwave in my room and I'm moving away in a month, so I don't want to buy an oven or any kitchen appliances, but I still want a steak, is it safe to cook it in the microwave?

Comment: safe, probably, tasty and appealing, no.

Comment: It will be a safe piece of vulcanized rubber.

Comment: That's perfect for a student like me!

Comment: Oh, man... that makes me really sad.  Just because you're a student doesn't mean you should accept substandard fare!

Comment: dont waste money on microwaved steak.  buy ramen instead or like.. hamburger helper..

Comment: Just be sure to thaw it first - http://what-if.xkcd.com/131/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is safe. It is really more a question of quality. I would suggest that, in your specific situation you get a browning dish. (It would be something that you could still use after your move, if you like.) Please see the excerpt below from  [this page](http://articles.philly.com/1992-04-22/food/26003164_1_flank-steak-microwave-dish) .

> There is nothing like a charbroiled steak straight off the grill. But for the times when you don't want to fire up the grill - or even get the broiler dirty - there is a way to sear steaks in the microwave on an accessory called a browning dish.
>
> A microwaved steak will not brown well without one, and the dish is really the only acceptable way to brown in the microwave.
>
> Browning dishes can be either flat rectangular plates or black skillets that are designed for the microwave.
>
> Embedded in the plate or skillet are metal strips that cause the microwaves to couple or link, producing an electrical current. The dish also is coated with a metal that is resistant to the electrical current.

You can read the rest of the article and the how-to information by following the link.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to address and answer @Bruno's concern with useful information.  I don't even like microwaved popcorn - don't even get me started on microwaved meats - but I also have the luxury of a good stove and a great oven.  I think you have addressed the only plausible solution to his query.  I would surely find a way to microwave meat before I would suck-down a bowl of MSG-salt-Ramen.

Comment: Your link is broken.